# Fix log plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want a plot with a log scale in x-axis and a "normal" y-axis.

I got a plot but I see a strange thing on my y-axis which I couldnt figure out.

```
breaks <- 10^(-10:10)
minor_breaks <- rep(1:9, 21)*(10^rep(-10:10, each=9))
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) +
  geom_line(size = 1, color = "blue") +
  scale_x_log10(breaks = breaks, minor_breaks = minor_breaks, limits = c(0.1,50)) +
  annotation_logticks()
```

[image]

What is this thing on the y-axis and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: what's breaks and minor_breaks?

Comment: breaks <- 10^(-10:10)
minor_breaks <- rep(1:9, 21)*(10^rep(-10:10, each=9))

Comment: Please add breaks and minor_breaks to the question.  Not just a comment.

Comment: `scale_x_log10` is irrelevant in the context of the question in fact

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the code below you can remove the black mess on the y-axis because it's the annotated tick marks you've added. Setting side = "b" indicates that you only want the tick marks on the x-axis (the bottom).

```
breaks <- 10^(-10:10) 
minor_breaks <- rep(1:9, 21)*(10^rep(-10:10, each=9))

g <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) +
  geom_line(size = 1, color = "blue") +
  scale_x_log10(breaks = breaks, minor_breaks = minor_breaks, limits = c(0.1,50)) +
  annotation_logticks(sides = "b")
g
```

Answer (score 1):

By default `annotation_logticks()` adds ticks to the bottom and left axis. You don't want ticks on the left (y-axis) because it isn't log-scaled. That's why it looks wrong.

Use the `sides =` argument to label only the bottom (x-axis):

```
g <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) +
  geom_line(size = 1, color = "blue") +
  scale_x_log10(breaks = breaks, minor_breaks = minor_breaks, limits = c(0.1, 50)) +
  annotation_logticks(sides = "b")
```